# PDOException only in certain use cases

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using an Articles class to pull data off my DB about ..articles. I can use instances to insert data, modify it but I can't seem to use it from a different set of pages.
Folder structure looks like this 
`/cms/conf.php` (with proven to work define("DB_DSN" [..] etc)

`/cms/classes/Article.php`

`/about.php`

in `about.php` I want to pull out data off my DB using a static function in my Article class:

```
   public static function getById($id) {
        $conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id";
        $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
        $row = $st->fetch();
        $conn = null;
        if ($row) return new Article($row);
    }
```

I call it like this:
`echo Article::getById(17)->content;`

To get a `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name'` [...] `PDO->__construct('DB_DSN', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD') #1`

However I can use the same method and the same method call syntax in my toy file `/cms/dataentry.php` **without problems** (from either command line or web browser).

I'm making wrong environment assumptions I suppose? `apps.php` does have `include 'cms/classes/Article.php';`

PHP version 5.3.2

Comment: It seems `DB_DSN` is invalid. Is this constant even defined?

Comment: Yep I've been using it to manually add and retrieve data with code in the `/cms/dataentry.php` file. (I just manually truncated the `define()` statement in my question)

Comment: I mean, is it defined the moment you try to use it? Try to `var_dump()` it, set `error_reporting()` to something (more) useful, ...

Answer (score 1):

`DB_DSN` looks like it isn't defined when you try to create a new `PDO` instance.

PHP automatically quotes undefined constants, which is why you're getting this in your error:

```
PDO->__construct('DB_DSN', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD')
```

You'll probably want to `require_once` the file that defines these constants wherever you need them

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however turns out the problem was different. 
In the `conf.php` I was given there was already a require for `Article.php`; suggesting apparently that I include `conf.php` in my pages and not touch `Article.php` any further. Doing what I did was just going in circles.